# Blueprints in flask does not work, Error 404. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, flask, web-deployment

I did everything according to the flask documentation, but I always get the error 404. I really don't get what I am doing wrong. Perhaps, someone can look at my code and give me a push in the direction of my mistake? It would be too generous, I am really stuck here for hours now and I am almost at the point to give up again. It is so frustrating.

my app:

```
import flask


app = flask.Flask(__name__)


def main():
    register_blueprints()
    app.run(debug=True)


def register_blueprints():
    from pypi_org.views import home_views
    from pypi_org.views import package_views

    app.register_blueprint(package_views.blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(home_views.blueprint)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

my home_views.py file

```
import flask

import pypi_org.services.package_service as package_service

blueprint = flask.Blueprint('home', __name__, template_folder='templates')


@blueprint.route('/')
def index():
    test_packages = package_service.get_latest_packages()
    return flask.render_template('home/index.html', packages=test_packages)


@blueprint.route('/about')
def about():
    return flask.render_template('home/about.html')
```

Comment: Can you provide links to the tutorial you're following?  I'm curious as to what the `pypi_org` package contains?

Comment: Sure. 
I follow this course currently. 
https://training.talkpython.fm/courses/details/building-data-driven-web-applications-in-python-with-flask-sqlalchemy-and-bootstrap

this is the git hub: Not sure if it public though:
https://github.com/talkpython/data-driven-web-apps-with-flask

Comment: the folder lloks like this C:.
├───infrastructure
├───services
├───static
├───templates
│   ├───home
│   └───shared
└───views

Comment: He has his own technique to route things, so for the question here I structured my code to fit the usual way I guess.

Comment: How are you running your app? If you're using `FLASK_APP=app.py flask run`, then `main()` won't get invoked, and blueprints won't get registered.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time!

I am not quite sure what you mean. I thought I start the app with app.run()
???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this in the 'final' github files provided for the course (see the link provided by OP), there's an addition of a couple lines in app.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
else:
    register_blueprints()
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps simplify `app.py`:

```
import flask
from pypi_org.views import home_views
from pypi_org.views import package_views

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(package_views.blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(home_views.blueprint)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (app.url_map)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Note the addition of the second last line prints all the URL routes to the terminal when you run the application, which helps for debugging.

Comment: Okay it somehow solved the problem, even though I do not get why?
Also it raised a new problem. My html is now not properly linked again and I am getting a jinja2 error... I am going crazy here hahaha

Comment: thank you for solving my first problem though. Can you elaborate perhaps why my code was not working? I

Comment: The `register_blueprints()` function in your original code doesn't `return app`.  If it did you could then change the `main()` function to begin with: `app = register_blueprints()` so when `app.run(debug=True)` is executed, you're working on the `app` object which has the blueprints registered.  This logic is clear in my example, as no functions are defined.  I prefer to keep `app.run()` in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause directly, as this is only for local execution, so it makes sense to have it there and not in a `main()` function elsewhere in the code.